# Complete code flow understanding of substrate and frame pallets

Tags: pallet, runtime

As a substrate developer I have gained some experience in writing pallets, benchmarking extrinsincs and aggregating those to the runtime. But now I wanted to understand the system very deeply. I am confused about the code flow. From where the execution starts, which pallet uses which pallets, how node is coded, what is the entire flow look like?

Can anyone put some guidance on this?

Comment: Can you provide a bit more focus in your question? Like for example, you want to understand how the outer node works? Or you want to go deeper into the runtime and understand how the runtime "orchestrates" everything? Take a look [here](https://docs.substrate.io/fundamentals/architecture/) for reference.

Comment: @Bruno, First I want to understand how the runtime orchestrates everything? From which pallet the execution starts, where the execution goes next like that? For example if we see a rust binary crate project execution starts from main.rs or if its a lib crate it start from lib.rs. So substrate is a collection of many lib crate right. So i want to understand the very low level execution flow. Am I clear with my question here?